# Sticky headers on SliverList

Tags: flutter

I've seen new flutter video and seen some interesting. (It's not typical sticky header or expandable list, so I don't know how to name it)

[Video](https://youtu.be/ORiTTaVY6mM?t=19) - watch from 0:20

Does anybody know how can I create such type of list with headers using SliverList?

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

One way is to create a `CustomScrollView` and pass a `SliverAppBar` pinned to `true` and a `SliverFixedExtentList` object with your Widgets.

Example:

```
List<Widget> _sliverList(int size, int sliverChildCount) {
    var widgetList = <Widget>[];
    for (int index = 0; index < size; index++)
      widgetList
        ..add(SliverAppBar(
           title: Text("Title $index"),
           pinned: true,
         ))
        ..add(SliverFixedExtentList(
          itemExtent: 50.0,
          delegate:
              SliverChildBuilderDelegate((BuildContext context, int index) {
                   return Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      color: Colors.lightBlue[100 * (index % 9)],
                      child: Text('list item $index'),
                   );
              }, childCount: sliverChildCount),
        ));

   return widgetList;
}

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      title: Text("Slivers"),
    ),
    body: CustomScrollView(
      slivers: _sliverList(50, 10),
    ),
  );
}
```

[image]

Comment: @JayMungara .. is sugar syntax.

Comment: For example,
var a = createA()..Do1()..Do2();

Comment: Is the same as, var a = createA(); a.Do1(); a.Do2();

Comment: how to use without SliverAppBar?

Comment: How to show only one sliver app bar at a time? Right now it just keeps on adding and in case of too many of those, layout looks weird.

Comment: this solution have performance issue when you have big list

Comment: use https://medium.com/geekculture/dynamically-pinned-list-headers-ee5aa23f1db4 to show only one sliver app bar at a time

Answer (score 36):

`SliverPersistentHeader` is the more generic widget behind `SliverAppBar` that you can use.

```
SliverPersistentHeader(
    delegate: SectionHeaderDelegate("Section B"),
    pinned: true,
),
```

And the `SectionHeaderDelegate` can be implement with something like:

```
class SectionHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final String title;
  final double height;

  SectionHeaderDelegate(this.title, [this.height = 50]);

  @override
  Widget build(context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) {
    return Container(
      color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor,
      alignment: Alignment.center,
      child: Text(title),
    );
  }

  @override
  double get maxExtent => height;

  @override
  double get minExtent => height;

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => false;
}
```