# How can I make DraggableScrollableSheet scroll up when dragging the handle, just like google map does

Tags: flutter

I am new to flutter. I am trying to add a little handle to hint the user to drag just like google map does. However, if I put a separate container above to show as a handle, there will be no drag effect when a user touches it. I understand that is because no scroll happens with the scrollcontroller.
If I put the handle inside the listView below in the blue box, it will scroll up as expected. However, at the top, the handle will scroll up away as the listView has more items.

Is there any way that I can manually scroll the sheet up when a user touches and drags the handle?

[image: handle bar for DraggableScrollableSheet]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please try this

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  bool leftClick = false;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: DraggableScrollableSheet(
        minChildSize: 0.1,
        maxChildSize: 0.9,
        initialChildSize: 0.3,
        builder: (BuildContext context, ScrollController scrollController) {
          return Container(
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            color: Colors.green,
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                Container(
                    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.9,
                    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                      controller: scrollController,
                      child: Column(
                        children: [
                          const SizedBox(
                            height: 50,
                          ),
                          ...List.generate(
                              50,
                              (index) => Container(
                                  height: 50, child: Text('Container $index')))
                        ],
                      ),
                    )),
                IgnorePointer(
                  child: Container(
                    color: Colors.green,
                    child: Row(
                      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                      children: [
                        Container(
                          margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20, bottom: 20),
                          height: 10,
                          width: 100,
                          decoration: BoxDecoration(
                              borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10),
                              color: Colors.grey),
                        ),
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Preview]

Comment: Please read my question, DragableScrollableSheet is in the title

Comment: Edited my answer with working codes. Please check

Comment: Thank you so much for the code, what a clever usage of IgnorePointer!

Comment: Yeah it was blocking the drag since it had no scroll controller. So ignored pointer and stacked the list.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer here

[flutter DraggableScrollableSheet with sticky headers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67092750/flutter-draggablescrollablesheet-with-sticky-headers)